# Trying to figure out why MulAssign is considered not implemented

Tags: rust

I'm quite new to rust and to familiarize my self with it I'm trying to implement my own matrix structs.

An other user made me realize that maybe I did not have enough info, so heres a minimum viable code that gives me the error. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0dcd5a8c2ebdecb80867addfe7d38ccc

MathData is a trait implemented by f32 and f64 to limit the generic to only these two.

```
pub trait MatData<T> {}
impl MatData<f64> for f64 {}
impl MatData<f32> for f32 {}
```

The matrix Struct and Implementation:

```
pub struct Mat4<T: MatData<T>> {
    data: [T; 16],
}

impl<T: MatData<T>> Index<usize> for Mat4<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &T {
        &self.data[i]
    }
}

impl<T: MatData<T>> IndexMut<usize> for Mat4<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.data[i]
    }
}

impl<T> MulAssign for Mat4<T>
where
    T: MatData<T> + Mul + Add + Mul<Output = T> + Add<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    fn mul_assign(&mut self, rhs: Self) {
        self[0] = self[0] * rhs[0] + self[1] * rhs[4] + self[2] * rhs[8] + self[3] * rhs[12];
        self[1] = self[0] * rhs[1] + self[1] * rhs[5] + self[2] * rhs[9] + self[3] * rhs[13];
        self[2] = self[0] * rhs[2] + self[1] * rhs[6] + self[2] * rhs[10] + self[3] * rhs[14];
        self[3] = self[0] * rhs[3] + self[1] * rhs[7] + self[2] * rhs[11] + self[3] * rhs[15];

        self[4] = self[4] * rhs[0] + self[5] * rhs[4] + self[6] * rhs[8] + self[7] * rhs[12];
        self[5] = self[4] * rhs[1] + self[5] * rhs[5] + self[6] * rhs[9] + self[7] * rhs[13];
        self[6] = self[4] * rhs[2] + self[5] * rhs[6] + self[6] * rhs[10] + self[7] * rhs[14];
        self[7] = self[4] * rhs[3] + self[5] * rhs[7] + self[6] * rhs[11] + self[7] * rhs[15];

        self[8] = self[8] * rhs[0] + self[9] * rhs[4] + self[10] * rhs[8] + self[11] * rhs[12];
        self[9] = self[8] * rhs[1] + self[9] * rhs[5] + self[10] * rhs[9] + self[11] * rhs[13];
        self[10] = self[8] * rhs[2] + self[9] * rhs[6] + self[10] * rhs[10] + self[11] * rhs[14];
        self[11] = self[8] * rhs[3] + self[9] * rhs[7] + self[10] * rhs[11] + self[11] * rhs[15];

        self[12] = self[12] * rhs[0] + self[13] * rhs[4] + self[14] * rhs[8] + self[15] * rhs[12];
        self[13] = self[12] * rhs[1] + self[13] * rhs[5] + self[14] * rhs[9] + self[15] * rhs[13];
        self[14] = self[12] * rhs[2] + self[13] * rhs[6] + self[14] * rhs[10] + self[15] * rhs[14];
        self[15] = self[12] * rhs[3] + self[13] * rhs[7] + self[14] * rhs[11] + self[15] * rhs[15];
    }
}
```

When using it like so:
`mat_a *= mat_b;`
I get this from the compiler:

> binary assignment operation `*=` cannot be applied to type `matrix::Mat4<T>`
> the trait `std::ops::MulAssign` is not implemented for `matrix::Mat4<T>`"

Comment: [Your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c253d59dee4132d2b7f8d4f857cec91a) compiles. What is the exact type of `mat_a` and `mat_b` ?

Comment: Mat4<f64> for both.

Comment: Could you please link or add the code you are trying ?

Comment: I just realized that maybe I did not have enough info, so heres a minimum viable code that gives me the error. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0dcd5a8c2ebdecb80867addfe7d38ccc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `MulAssign` implementation:

```rust
impl<T> MulAssign for Mat4<T>
where
    T: MatData<T> + Mul + Add + Mul<Output = T> + Add<Output = T> + Copy,
```

is not general enough as `Transform` implementation which is:

```rust
impl<T> Transform<T>
where
    T: MatData<T> + Add + Mul + Copy,
```

The difference is `MulAssign` implementation explicitly states the associated types of `Mul` and `Add` as `Output = T`, this makes the `MulAssign` impl less general than `Transform` impl and as a result you cannot use `MulAssign` behavior in `Transform`

To use it you either need to make `MulAssign` more general(*according to your implementation it is not possible*) or(*then*) you need to make `Transform` less general like :

```rust
impl<T> Transform<T>
where
    T: MatData<T> +  Mul<Output = T> + Add<Output = T> + Copy,
{
```